# Package name that do not have name as the app itself

Tags: android

From my Android 10 industrial device (not a smartphone or watch or TV) I have 165 collected package names via ADB. On this device is working app called 'Wireless Update' version 5.28. I can't tell witch of those 165 packages is the 'Wireless Update' app. Rest of the packages I am interested in have names that are easy to recognize. Not this one :)

Thanks in advance,
Marcin

Comment: Install some app which allows you to view both the app name and the package ID, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools&hl=en_US&gl=US)

Comment: OK I will use it some time. Is there another way? I can't install any APK on the device :/

Comment: Since you mentioned using the ADB to get your package names, what about using the `pm` command in an ADB shell?
It's not a very efficient way of doing things but you could run all of your packages through `pm dump <package>` to get some more info on each package. `pm list packages -f` might also help to see some more info based on the file names provided by the command.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.
I want to set some setting via JSON (turn on dark mode, turn on camera stabillization, turn off bluetooth etc.) - were to look samples for that?
For now I've managed leave one app on home screet and hide the other ones.
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "packagename": "com.microsoft.teams"
    },
    {
      "packagename": ""
    },
    {
      "packagename": ""
    },
    {
      "packagename": ""
    },
    {
      "packagename": ""
    }
  ],
  
  "inclusive": false,
  "packages": [
    "com.android.settings",
  ]
}